# C - Warning is shown when defining function in a macro

Tags: c, macros

I am trying to build some generic things. And it needs a macro to define some functions (not "function-like" macro, I mean normal function in C).

There is pseudo code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define array_type_init(type)                  \
    typedef struct array_##type##_s            \
    {                                          \
        type *items;                           \
        size_t length;                         \
    } array_##type##_t;                        \
                                               \
    array_##type##_t array_##type##_initiate() \
    {                                          \
        array_##type##_t new_array;            \
        new_array.items = NULL;                \
        new_array.length = 0;                  \
        return new_array;                      \
    }

int main()
{
    array_type_init(int); // Warning is shown.

    array_int_t new_arr = array_int_initiate(); // It works fine.

    return 0;
}
```

But my IDE showed a gcc warning in line 21. It said I may already define function `array_int_initiate`. The error code is C\C++(159). (I didn't show the original error message here since my error message is not English.)

I think my syntax may be wrong for the function definition in macro. How do I fix the code to clear the waning?

My gcc version: 12.1.0

OS: Windows 11

Comment: The first of 4 errors and 1 warning I got from MSCV is the first line in `main`, line 21 `missing ';' before '{'`. The others are all line 23 marked "works fine".

Comment: @WeatherVane Probably because of the nested function definition? Gnu C allows such as an extension.

Comment: @AdrianMole thanks I had not got that far. Next step was to use text editor to make the actual macro expansions. "How to write obfuscated code" :/

Comment: While GCC does allow nested functions, that's not what you want.  Move the line `array_type_init(double);` line outside of `main()`.

Comment: @AdrianMole I think so. I move the function ```array_type_init``` out of the ```main``` block and the warning is clear now. Thanks guys.

Comment: Replace `array_type_init(double)` with `array_type_init(int)`, and it should compile. You're initializing with `double` but using `int`.

Comment: protip: use `gcc -E your_file.c` to see the contents after expanding the macros (and includes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The effect of your macro is to define a function at the point of invocation. Standard C does not allow nested function definitions. So you should invoke the macro a the global scope:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define array_type_define(type)                   \
    typedef struct array_##type##_t {             \
        type *items;                              \
        size_t length;                            \
    } array_##type##_t;                           \
                                                  \ 
    array_##type##_t array_##type##_initiate(void) {  \
        array_##type##_t new_array = { NULL, 0 }; \
        return new_array;                         \
    }

array_type_define(int); // defines array_int_t and array_int_initiate();

int main() {
    array_int_t new_arr = array_int_initiate(); // Should work fine.

    return 0;
}
```

Note that this macro cannot be used for qualified types: `unsigned int` or `long long` or pointer types `char *`... You might want to pass the identifier part as an argument. Defining this function as `static inline` will prevent multiple definitions in projects with multiple files:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define array_type_define(type, name)             \
    typedef struct array_##name##_t {             \
        type *items;                              \
        size_t length;                            \
    } array_##name##_t;                           \
                                                  \ 
    static inline array_##name##_t array_##name##_initiate(void) {  \
        return (array_##name##_t){ NULL, 0 };     \
    }

// define array_int_t and array_int_initiate();
array_type_define(int, int);
// define array_uint_t and array_uint_initiate();
array_type_define(unsigned int, uint);
// define array_string_t and array_string_initiate();
array_type_define(const char *, string);

int main() {
    array_int_t new_arr = array_int_initiate(); // Should work fine.

    return 0;
}
```